# Is there any kind of ELO Hell In DOTA 2?

Tags: dota-2

Is there any kind of ELO Hell In DOTA 2? If yes, how to avoid it?

Comment: If you think this because of my comment in your previous question - I was mistaken. I thought you were talking about LoL, not Dota 2

Comment: @Mathias711 So you think there is no ELO Hell In DOTA 2 ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I did a quick google and the opinions are divided. I have no experience with it, but I thought that you asked the question because of my (deleted) comment in your previous question

Comment: @Mathias711 I was thinking about ELO Hell before your comment. But after your comment I wanted more to ask that question here.

Comment: Please define Elo hell.

Comment: @T_O I understand ELO Hell as a condition when player is playing good but system is not ranking him apropriatly or does not mathching him with good teammates all the time.

Comment: @vasili111 well then there is no such thing as Elo hell, but that's something really hard to disprove. The matchmaking system is pretty transparent once you complete the calibration  phase. You can see the MMR of every player at the end of each games and the local bad and good performances are to be attributed to randomness (good/bad mood, preferred hero, winning/losing streak, etc.). If you want some elements of evidence I'd suggest you look for Juice's experiment

Comment: @T_O I linked Juice experiment in my answer 3 min ago =D Great minds

Comment: Why down votes?

Comment: People are downvoting because ELO hell is an unpopular myth, used by players who can't deal with the fact that they aren't placed where they think they deserve. Good players with smurf accounts prove constantly that there's no such thing, play well enough and you will rise in ELO/MMR. There's no reason why a good player would intentionally be held back by the system.

Comment: @Tobberoth But I don't understand why they are down voting, because as a completely new to MOBA games and particularly to DOTA 2 it is reasonable question from newcomer that sees all that posts while searching in google about various aspects of playing DOTA 2. Maybe they don't like the belief of some people in ELO Hell, but it is different from quality of question asked.

Comment: @vasili111 I agree, I did not downvote and don't see the point in downvoting your post. Better to have someone ask with answers explaining how ELO hell is a myth, than more new people considering it.

Comment: @vasili111 I also think the downvotes come from people who don't like the term Elo hell when referring to Dota, as the used term is MMR.. Not that it matters but a lot of people are sensitive. Don't say Dota is a MOBA either or you will probably receive 10 downvotes sadly

Comment: I downvoted the question because  it lacks explanation. I'm an experienced DotA player so I've heard what the ELO hell is in LoL but it's really non existent in DotA 2 so any DotA player that have not heard of it might just have downvote it because they simply don't understand the question. Defining what you call ELO hell and giving a bit more content to your question woudl certainly be better =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer : No. They have been [many discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/22m208/my_elo_hell_experiment_is_finally_over/) on this topic in DotA 2 and as long as you try your best to win, you can raise your MMR and reach your full potential without getting stuck in any "ELO Hell".

For the record, the experiment made in the link above consist in :

- A Highly rated player (5400-5600 MMR)
- Using a low calibrated account (2900 MMR)
- Played 144 consecutives game with a 85% winrate
- Brought the MMR of the 2900 account up to 5400
- Raised the victory ratio from 47% to 60% on the account

Comment: As long as you play at a level above the MMR you are currently at, you will rise over time. A good case study can be found here. http://www.playdota.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1398477

Comment: @patchandthat this tread is linked in the dissucion I linked in my answer

Comment: Of course it is, sorry!

Answer (score 6):

ELO hell has very little to do with MMR and almost everything to do with attitude. Negative reinforcement lowers performance while positive reinforcement increases it.

The knock on effect of this in DOTA 2 is that if you are losing games you will feel unskilled or feel that your team-mates have let you down and continue to lose and on the flip side, when you are winning you become more confident, positive and communicative.

To avoid this you need to pay as much attention to your mood and attitude as you in game plays. Avoid being a toxic player or letting other toxic players affect your mood.

Answer (score -2):

Of course it exists. If you are stuck at let's say 3k mmr you simply won't get out of this. Reasons are you can't decide a team game like Dota on your own and in this mmr region your team will always cost you the game, regardless what you are doing. The main problem is that the mmr change is only based on the result of the game, this might be ok for good mmr regions but it is the least distinguishing qualifier for low games. It should only be based on your personal performance and not include the game result at all.

Comment: The reason why you are stuck at 3K MMR is because you deserve that 3K MMR, and isn't proficient enough to reach 4K or 5K. If you deserve that 4K or 5K, you will reach there. Thus, there is no such thing as ELO hell in Dota 2.

Comment: That's the typical answer, unfortunately it is not true. The influence of one person is just too little in Dota 2, below some mmr the result of the game is just like rolling a dice. There is a treshold where won't be able to get up if you are not super pro. Compared to CS:GO for example where you can improve yourself to get up. There might be an ELO hell as well at very low ranks but it is simply nothing compared to Dota 2, because one person can make a difference, ELO is based on personal performance and not on a game result that does not tell anything about the individual skill.

Comment: That's true, but every single teammate counts, including you. I've seen people turning the tide of matches by their own powers only. Also, you are not correct in saying that you can't choose your teammates, you can actually make a party and play together you know.

Comment: Party MMR might be at least a little bit useful in this game, it still suffers from the same problem that the game is only calculating points based on the team winning or losing. I simply don't get why they released this match making system, of course it leads into the ELO hell problem that the game suffers now. If you have a team of 5 then you can probably enjoy ranked party games, single ranked is just bullshit. Of course it is hard to base a system like this on individual performance but without doing this the whole system is useless. I really hope they solve the ELO hell problem.

Comment: The one single constant in every team battle you've lost was you.

Comment: @Shadur that's the core of the ELO hell myth. If every player has an X chance of sucking, and you don't suck, you are simply statistically likely to have the better team.